# How to avoid spring application failure due to BeanCreationException caused by third party package

Tags: spring-boot, spring-aop, nats.io, beancreationexception

I am using a third-party package in my spring boot app. This [one](https://github.com/nats-io/spring-nats) to be specific. This package has a [method](https://github.com/nats-io/spring-nats/blob/3301eba097f3ad60b66c8d4e9cc7246787f91a74/nats-spring/src/main/java/io/nats/spring/boot/autoconfigure/NatsAutoConfiguration.java#L57) that creates a bean when the application starts. The bean is only created successfully if this package is able to talk to nats service. In most cases, this all works fine. The remote server is available, the bean is created, my spring boot apps boots up correctly.

But there are some edge cases when remote nats servers might not be up. This causes my spring boot app to fail to start as the above function throws `BeanCreationException`

How can I avoid this i.e avoid my spring app boot failure due to this exception when the nats server is not up?

Note: It is fine for my spring app/business logic to be up and running if this bean (connections to nats service) is not available.

Specific Exception :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'natsConnection' defined in class path resource [io/nats/spring/boot/autoconfigure/NatsAutoConfiguration.class]:
Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [io.nats.client.Connection]:
Factory method 'natsConnection' threw exception; nested exception is java.io.IOException: Unable to connect to NATS server.\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:655)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:635)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1176)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:897)\n\tat org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879)\n\tat
```

Comment: we have a docker-compose file to spin up services we depend on, since we have this problem in a lot of places: even our db migrations need a bean to talk to a broker to "lock" migrations in case multiple nodes would try to run db migrations.

Comment: You have 3k reputation, you know the drill: Please help other people to help you by providing information like at least exception call stack, aspects (especially pointcuts used). Both are relevant here as you have tagged the question _spring-aop_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bean `natsConnection` is created by auto-configuration and annotated with `@ConditionalOnMissingBean`. Such beans are instantiated *after* your own beans.

You can create your own bean of this type, `io.nats.client.Connection`, and register it as `natsConnection`. This bean should have no own logic. When called for the first time, it should create a worker instance via `NatsAutoConfiguration.natsConnection(...)` and then delegate all calls to it.

Because of `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` the default bean from the NATS library will not be instantiated and only your bean will be created.

Comment: Hmm.. but won't spring call the library to create auto configuration bean after my custom bean? I am wondering if that would cause some sort of duplication?

Comment: @nitinsh99: I have updated the answer. Because of `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` only your bean will be crated and the default one will not.